# How to make a 2 feet long concrete pillars for deck posts in Quebec

Tags: concrete, deck, canada

I live in Quebec and I read articles from CAA and Rona (Lowes in the rest of Canada) stating that the concrete pillars for building decks posts should be between 4 or 5 feet tall in ground below the frost line to avoid any issue. I am planning to do the number *2 Concrete Pillars Without Footings* from this article [install a deck foundation](https://www.rona.ca/en/workshop/diy/install-a-deck-foundation)

Talking with a Home Depot girl who knows well her job told me that I don't need to be that depth but 2 feet in ground + 6 inches of gravel first using those yellow cardboard quikrete building forms, adding that the weight of the deck is enough to hold the posts there.

Let's say I am planning to isolate and avoid contact of the snow with the posts during the winter. Have you experienced any issue building a deck with 2 feet concrete pilars in ground + 6 inches of gravel below in Quebec instead from the 4 feet long concrete pillar? Any move or stability issues apart from the theory?

EDIT: I mentioned Quebec, but I want to specify I live in Montreal's  south shore. This may change the idea that I could live in the North where snow and cold is stronger than in Montreal.

Comment: I would ask a local contractor for a bid, to see what he says, and dont tell him about your plan

Comment: Point of order— it’s mostly Rona in the rest of Canada. There’s like one Lowes in my entire metro area and six Rona.

Comment: When putting something in the ground that is not below the frost line, people are usually not happy inside of a few years.  Have put in fence posts not far enough and the next year they would be raise up by about a foot.  Dig down or use a floating system.

Comment: @RibaldEddie thanks for pointing that! I never bought in any hardware store outside Quebec and here we do not have Lowes. This made think that Lowes is for the rest of Canada. Nevertheless, Lowes, Rona and RenoDepot are from the same corporation.

Comment: @crip659 thanks for pointing that out. My existing deck has concrete footings blocks at a  ground level. They do not have gravel below and over the years they went buried more and more inclining the deck over the years. As I planning to repair it I thought that it was a good idea to drill and put concrete, but I can see that can create another issue in fact. I will need to pay more and make them 4 feet long

Comment: @knowitall that is great idea. I didn't do it first by the fact the contractors are so busy and if they talk to you they want to make you sign a contract. The market these days are so aggressive. But I think it worths trying!

Comment: It is usually much cheaper to pay and do it right the first time, than to keep redoing it.  Usually it costs more to prepare to dig a hole than the digging itself, if doing it by a machine.

Comment: Thank you for your honest comment. I bought a few concrete bags for fences and posts that are 10$ and need 3 per post. As I need to do 6 drills and 6 cardboard building forms at 9$ it is gonna increase my budget but as you said in the long term it is worthy!  The auger machine is not that long tho! I saw that people use the yellow quikrete concrete bags 5000psi which are $4 but the label does not mention the quantity for posts. I will try to ask at Home Depot!

Comment: Can usually get extensions to augers/post hole diggers.

Comment: "the weight of the deck is enough to hold the posts there" If the weight of your entire house isn't enough to hold it in place on a 2' deep footing (thus the code quotes that footings should be 4-5' deep), how in the world is a lightweight deck going to be heavy enough to keep it from moving when the ground freezes? Your HD girl may be friendly and a good salesman, but she's not knowledgeable.

Answer (score 3):

The woman working at the hardware store is absolutely not qualified to give construction advice; she didn't even ask you any questions whatsoever about your deck.

You must go below the frost line when any of the following are true (I'm sure there are more than this, but I digress):

- The deck is not a stand-alone unit (ie. it's attached to a building (eg. house)
- The deck is more than 55 metres square
- The deck has a roof
- The deck is more than 30" from ground to the top of the walking surface at any point

The ground doesn't care what the weight of the deck is. Frost can and will shift your posts if not below the frost line.

Despite any rules, just rent a hole auger, spend a bit more on concrete, and do the job properly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I rented a 8in diameter auger machine for one since it is just me. It was so hard to do it but myself and I could dig 4 holes. One at 4 ft 3 in and the other three at 3 ft and 1 in. Ground was so compacted and machine couldn't go deeper than this I struggled so much doing this, in fact, the machine stopped drilling. Frost line is 4 ft according to QC rules and I should do it at 5 or 6 . I proceeded with the 6 inches of gravel and built my concrete pillars. My deck is 20 ft wide and 13 ft long. I will test it on winter. I am scared as hell.

Comment: You should have gotten help to do it properly. You wouldn't have to sit and worry all year.

Answer (score 2):

Generally in Quebec the frost line is 5 feet. 2 feet is insufficient.

Comment: wow, the OP knows that, how does it help him

Comment: I think the answer has all the relevant information: ** 2 feet is insufficient. ** I’m also guessing that the Home Depot staffer doesn’t have a contractor’s license or PEng designation.